# Data Masking Request/Response Content during proxy trace on Apigee Layer

Tags: apigee, data-masking

A SB for a proxy on the Apigee service is returning a string, as opposed to an XML or JSON response.  This string may include confidential data, which we would like to mask.

Attempting to set up a DataMaskConfiguration like this:

```
<MaskDataConfiguration name="default">
  <Variables>
    <Variable>response.content</Variable>
  </Variables>
</MaskDataConfiguration>
```

Successfully masks the variable response.content in the Variables section of any policies using it during the trace.  However, I continue to see the string in the Response Content > Body section of the trace.

Because the response is a string, as opposed to XML or JSON path, I am unable to parse it using either part of the mask data config.

Does anyone know of the variables that I can set int he MaskDataConfiguration to mask the data being presented in the Request and Response Content sections when viewing a policy in the trace?  Or, is there another method of doing so outside the scope of MaskDataConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no easy way to do this. You could try masking the variables 'request.content', 'message.content', 'response.content' to see if that works.